# "folding" or "hiding" text in vim

Tags: vim, terminal

This is a complete shot in the dark and I am not sure of the viability of this, but this functionality would be great for me if it was available somehow.

text editors like sublimetext have an option where you can "fold up" blocks of code you are not directly using or have no concern about. For example, imagine an EJS template like so (obviously just for visuals):

```
<div class="container">
  <FORM name="form">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <% $.each(something, function(k,v) { %>
          <td>
            <input type="<%=v.type%>" name="<%=v.name%>"> <%=v.attribute%>
          </td>
        <% } %>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </FORM>
</div>
```

Now let's say I'm working with this and finished with the FORM so I don't want it to be in my HTML so I can focus more easily on other things, like layout. EG, I want it to look like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <FORM name="form"> ... </FORM>
</div>
```

would such a thing be possible in vim?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course.

You should type `:h 'folds'` to get help on folds.

In short:

`zf` creates a fold (you can select the text with visual mode beforehand or use a motion)
`zo` opens the fold under the cursor
`zc` closes it

Most fold commands start with `z` (mnemonic is Z looks like a fold of paper)

I recommend checking out these tutorials on vim:
http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/

Answer (score 2):

Try highlighting the block of code that you want to fold and then use 
`za`. Use `za` again to unfold the block of code.

See `:h folding` for more information on folding in Vim.

As a side note for your particular example, you can use the plugin [MatchTagAlways](https://github.com/Valloric/MatchTagAlways) to quickly highlight code around html tags.